# How to process an sql query with the word "only"?

Tags: sql

Given a table of people and a table of the places that they attend:
If I wish to find "People who 'only' attend weddings", how would I design a query so that the result includes only people who attend weddings and nothing else?

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a query where you get all the people who have gone to a wedding and then filter out anyone who has been to anything other than a wedding.

```
SELECT Distinct p.FullName
FROM dbo.People p
JOIN dbo.PlacesTheyGo ptg ON ptg.PeopleID = p.PeopleID
WHERE ptg.Place = 'Wedding' 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.PlacesTheyGo ptg2 
WHERE ptg2.PeopleID = p.PeopleID 
AND ptg2.Place <> 'Wedding')
```